# SQL Oracle 01722 Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle

Iam a SQL newbie but I need to rewrite something to get data from several databases.

First, the code I try to execute:

```
SELECT aeabwbbn
       || aeeancode                           AS EAN,
       ( lglagerbestand - lgauftragsbestand ) AS BESTAND,
       aeform
       || aequal
       || aefb                                AS ARTIKELNUMMER,
       aefb,
       lgfb
FROM   lagerbestand
       join artikelean
         ON lgfirma = artikelean.aefirma
            AND lgform = artikelean.aeform
            AND lgqual = artikelean.aequal
            AND lggroesse = artikelean.aegroesse
            AND lgfb = artikelean.aefb
```

the problem is the last row. Everything is working fine till I inclute the last row.
I thought it is because it has a different format, but every output is numeric. There are just numbers in this query.

So I tried `CAST(LGFB AS INTEGER) = ARTIKELEAN.AEFB` and `LGFB = CAST(ARTIKELEAN.AEFB AS INTEGER)` but that didn't work neither.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: What are LGFB and ARTIKELEAN.AEFB columns' datatypes?

Comment: Can you try `AND TO_NUMBER(lgfb) = TO_NUMBER(artikelean.aefb)`

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If one value is a number and the other a string, then Oracle (and SQL in general) will do the comparison as a number -- causing the conversion problem.

The simplest method is to convert the values to strings rather than integers:

```
TO_CHAR(LGFB) = TO_CHAR(ARTIKELEAN.AEFB)
```

Note that this might not do what you actually want.  For instance, one value might be `'0001'` and the other `1` and these would not be equal as strings.

Comment: This was it! I only tried to convert it into a numeric format, but that worked now. Than you!